# TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable Pysarpk, when joining two tables

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

so i am trying to 2 join 2 data frames and in doing so i am getting the following error.

> TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

I am loading data as simple csv files, following is the schema loaded from CSVs.

> root
>    |-- movie_id,title: string (nullable = true)
>
> root
>    |-- user_id,movie_id,tag,timestamp: string (nullable = true)

following is my implementation for loading

```
df1 = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("collaborative/titles.csv", header=True, sep="|")
df2 = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("collaborative/tags.csv", header=True, sep="|")
df1.printSchema()
df2.printSchema()
df1.alias("df1").join(df2.alias("df2"), col("df1.movie_id").equalTo(col("df2.movie_id"))).select(col("df2.*"))
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no method called `equalTo` on a column object. When you do `col("df1.movie_id").equalTo` it assumes you are accessing a nested field in the `movie_id` and returns another column, and hence the error: *column object is not callable*.

```
print(col('df1.movie_id').equalTo)
# Column<b'df1.movie_id[equalTo]'>
```

To fix the problem, follow the [correct join syntax here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.join).

In your case, the simplest solution is to drop irrelevant column from `df1` before join so you don't have to create aliases for data frames and select later:

```
df1.select('movie_id').join(df2, 'movie_id').show()
```

Comment: I got this error
`pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "cannot resolve '`movie_id`' given input columns: [movie_id,title];;\n'Project ['movie_id]\n+- Relation[movie_id,title#10] csv\n"`

Comment: It doesn't seem like your data is read in correctly. You need to check that first. Possibly `sep="\\|"` -

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
d1 = df1.alias("df1")
d2 = df2.alias("df2")
d1.join(d2,d1.movie_id == d2.movie_id).select('df2.*')
```

You can refer to pyspark join examples [here](http://www.learnbymarketing.com/1100/pyspark-joins-by-example/).

Comment: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'movie_id', getting this error

Comment: Did you try joining it the way mentioned in the link, or something like `df1.join(df2, on=['movie_id'], how='right')`?